# Create cloud optimized GeoTIFF without re-encoding?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a lot of jpeg-in-geotiff imagery that I would like to convert to Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF. Is there any way to do that without re-encoding the pixel values?

I'm trying to avoid paying the price of:

- lossy + lossy compression that results from feeding a JPEG source to a JPEG output file, and
- lossy + lossless that comes from feeding a JPEG source to lossless output file, which means x4+ storage requirements

Comment: Interesting. With the old recipe https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/CloudOptimizedGeoTIFF it seems that the overviews can be copied as they are but the main image may really go through the jpeg-to-jpeg cycle. There should be an option `-co COPY_SRC_TIFF_TILES=YES` if source already has usable tiles as you certainly have. But perhaps `-co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES` does it already.

Comment: Cross posted to _gdal-dev_ mailng list, http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Create-cloud-optimized-geotiff-without-re-encoding-td5457572.html). @user30184 from that thread it's not clear that copy overviews is actually doing that, copying.

Comment: @user30184 I now have another use case for your copy-src suggestion: using `nearblack` to add a mask or alpha band to a jpeg-in-tiff image without re-encoding the data-bearing pixels. (I tried using output .vrt but _"ERROR 1: Writing through VRTSourcedRasterBand is not supported."_)

Comment: Looks like this will be possible with [GDAL 3.7](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc90_read_compressed_data.html)